# Table cells deform after entering input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, html-input

This is something similar to what I have:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tdCollection = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < tdCollection.length; i++) {
   var field = document.createElement('input');
    field.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    field.setAttribute('name', 'Field');
    field.setAttribute('value', tdCollection[i].textContent);
    tdCollection[i].innerHTML = "";
    tdCollection[i].appendChild(field);
  }
  
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A very long text</td>
    <td>tinyTxt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A very long text</td>
    <td>tinyTxt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button name="edit">Edit</button>
```

I'd like the table cells to maintain their original width even after pressing the Edit button. Setting the input fields width as the one of their parent cell would be ideal, but also resizing the fields width as its value and using `overflow: hidden` could work if there is no way to fix them to the cells width.

Thank you for the help :D

**EDIT**

I'm trying to retain the natural width of every column, I'd like to avoid having to have equal width on every column, if there is a way.

Comment: It is the input element that is the problem. In your CSS set the width of the input i.e. input { width: 2em;} and see if that helps.

Comment: @jeff I don't think that would be ideal, there are columns with long text like a full name and others with a single number, therefore the cells width are already very different. That's why I was looking for a way to define the input fields width relative to their parent cell.

Comment: Check out this example. It's all in the CSS. https://codepen.io/rhroyston/pen/dXdPEx

Comment: @RonRoyston Your example makes all the columns equal in their width with `table-layout:fixed;`, I'm trying to retain the natural width of every column.

Comment: where in this example is there an input element?

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed height and width for `td` and for the `input` you are appending to `td`.

Try the following way:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var cellWidth = document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth;
var cellHeight = document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells[0].offsetHeight;
console.log(cellHeight)
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tdCollection = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < tdCollection.length; i++) {
   var field = document.createElement('input');
    field.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    field.setAttribute('name', 'Field');
    field.setAttribute('value', tdCollection[i].textContent);
    field.style.width = (cellWidth - (4 + 4)) + 'px'; // removing approximate border of input element from left and right to fit into td.
    field.style.height = (cellHeight) + 'px'; // removing approximate border of input element from left and right to fit into td.
    tdCollection[i].innerHTML = "";
    tdCollection[i].appendChild(field);
  }
  
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/*table td, input {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}*/
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>A very long text</td>
    <td>tinyTxt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A very long text</td>
    <td>tinyTxt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button name="edit">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Setting a fixed width for `td` was my backup solution, if I found no way to do what I'm asking for. I'm trying to retain the natural width of every column.